# Would it matter if baryon asymmetry was the opposite?

Tags: antimatter, matter

If the quantity of matter of antimatter was switched, would it change anything?

Answer (score 0):

Not really. If we were made of antimatter, we would think of matter as antimatter. Antimatter is really the same as matter, just with an opposite charge and opposite lepton/baryon numbers. The laws of physics would be virtually the same. However, if we were made of matter in a universe that was mostly antimatter, we'd have to be very careful not to get annihilated.

Comment: thanks, but there probably would not be antimatter floating around...

Comment: "The laws of physics would be the same and everything. "... and you know this because of which evidence? :-)

Comment: "the laws of physics for antiparticles are almost identical to those for particles; any difference is a tiny effect" - http://www.scientificamerican.com/article/what-is-antimatter-2002-01-24/ was one source I've read this at

Comment: "Almost the same" is not the same and "a tiny effect" is not no effect. This is precisely why this question is such a fascinating one. The SciAm article condescendingly refuses to address it: "Recently both the NA48 experiment at CERN and the KTeV experiment at Fermilab have directly measured this asymmetry with enough precision to establish it." — never saying what the asymmetry is.